# Check proof that if $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{k}(a_n+\frac{k}{a_n})$ with $k>1$ and $a_1>0$, then $a_n\to\sqrt {\frac{k}{k-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a Sequence such that $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{k}(a_n+\frac{k}{a_n}), k>1, a_1>0$, show that $\{ a_n \}$ converges to $ \sqrt {\frac{k}{k-1}}$

**My attempt**

case 1: $a_{n+1}-a_n \leq 0 \\ \frac{1}{k}(a_n + \frac{k}{a_n})-a_n \leq 0 \\ a_n^2+k-ka_n^2 \leq 0 \\ a_n \geq \sqrt {\frac{k}{k-1}}$

Here sequence is decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt {\frac{k}{k-1}}$. so $a_n$ is convergent

**Case 2:** if $a_{n+1} - a_n \geq 0,$ i get

$a_k \leq \sqrt {\frac{k}{k-1}}$

Here sequence is increasing and bounded above.

SO given sequence is convergent. Let the convergence limit be l, then $l=1/k (l+ k/l)$ gives given limit.

can you pls tell me is this correct approach?

Comment: This is not a valid proof. You may have $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ for some values of $n$ and $a_{n+1} > a_n$ for other values of $n$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sir any clue how to approach this problem? I have this doubt in mind...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if we make assumption $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ then it should be true all all terms of sequence. If for some p : $a_{p+1}>= a_p$ then using the second property, i will have opposite of what i assumed. So i think this case may not arise. Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Please have some rigor. Without symbols like $\exists$ or $\forall$, nothing makes sense in what you wrote.

Comment: This seems to be confusing systematically $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: @Magneto How do you know that $(a_n)$ is monotonic?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire i got where i went wrong. I assumed it as increasing sequence or decreasing sequence. In that case, i proved it convergent. I need to also prove monotonicity of sequence....How to do this? Any clue?

Comment: Starting with different values $a_1$, one sees that the series is not monotonous for all starting values.

Comment: @Andreas Pls see this,  $a_{n+1}> 2/\sqrt k$ (by arithmetic mean > geometric mean). Now if $-2<k<2, $ then $2/\sqrt k > \sqrt {\frac{k}{k-1}} \implies a_n$ is decreasing sequence.  But  i need to force a condition that -2<k<2 i.e., 1<k<2

Comment: You are not interested in $k<2$, are you?

Comment: @Andreas Tq Sir, how to mark this as duplicate? or should i delete this post?

Comment: @Andreas this type of proof will not strike to my mind ....good 1

Comment: > should i delete this post?  --> You don't have to. There are many duplicate questions around which sometimes actually helps to find them.